# Show next/previous date on button click

Tags: ios, iphone

I have 2 button, one for increase the current date and one for decrease the date, so can you tell me how can I manage it I have using to show the current date in textfield by this way:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateformate setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];

date_String=[dateformate stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
_dateTF.text = date_String;
```

Comment: Check the below post which could solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code,

```
//This code will give you next date from current date

NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setDay:1]; // you can change this as per your requirement, this will increase +1 date
NSDate *nextDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];


// This code will give previous date from current date

NSDate *today1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian1 = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents1 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents1 setDay:-1]; // you can change this as per your requirement, this will decrease -1 date
NSDate *previousDate = [gregorian1 dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents1 toDate:today1 options:0];
```

You can change date formate, with you desire date format. Hope this helps.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
  NSDate *decreaseDate= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-60 * 60 * 24 sinceDate:<somedate>];
  NSDate *inceraseDate= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 24 sinceDate:<somedate>];
```

The above code snippet will helps you to get the previous and next date.